Rust program has faster runtimes when threads call a function with extracted logic rather than having the logic written in the thread closure. Why?
I am learning Rust and decided to implement my own project--a file compression tool--using the concepts discussed in the book.  I was experimenting with using multi-threading (specifically the mpsc crate) for the compression process, and noticed that my first stab at a multi-threaded solution was slower than my single-threaded implementation.
I tried a couple different things, and decided to extract a majority of the logic written within the thread out to a separate function.  Therefore, the thread would simply make a call to that function.  This minor change significantly increased runtime performance.  To be more specific, when compressing a 70 MB file, the single threaded solution took about 1700 ms, the first multi-threaded solution took about 2000 ms, and the second multi-threaded solution took about 600 ms (all of these times were averaged from 50 runs of compressing that 70 MB file).
Below are code snippets to give more context behind my implementation, since it's very possible that something I'm doing (allocating a vector on the stack, calling seek, etc.) could be the underlying reason for the performance difference. Please excuse any bad Rust programming.  I'm still learning, so if you have any suggestions, please throw them at me!
// logic that WAS directly written in the thread closure--it's now extracted to this function:
fn encode_segment<T>(
    t: &mut T,
    offset_from_start: usize,
    num_bytes_to_read: usize, 
    encodings_on_stack: &[(u256, u8); 256]
) -> Vec<u8> where T: Seek + Read + Sync + Send {
    if let Err(_) = t.seek(SeekFrom::Start(offset_from_start as u64)) {
        better_exit(vec!["Failed to set cursor to required byte"], EXIT_CODE_FILE_ERR);
    }

    let mut byte_vec: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    let mut byte_buf = vec![0; num_bytes_to_read];
    let mut bit_container = BitContainer::new();
    let mut last_byte_bitmask = 0xFF;
    let mut tot_bytes_read = 0;

    // logic to read and compress `num_bytes_to_read` bytes from `t`
    // left it out because it's a lot of code, and I think unnecessary to include

    byte_vec
}

// thread spawn and closure that uses `encode_segment`
let thread_spawn = thread::Builder::new().spawn(move || {
    let mut buf_for_file = BufReader::with_capacity(
        MAX_SEGMENT_SIZE, 
        open_file(&in_path_ptr_cl.read().unwrap())
    );
    let stk_enc_rwl = match stk_enc_ptr_cl.read() {
        Ok(nested) => nested,
        Err(_) => better_exit(
            vec!["`RwLock` containing `stk_enc_ptr_cl` is poisoned"], 
            EXIT_CODE_DEV_ERR
        ),
    };
    // the slower implementation did not use `encode_segment`
    // instead, the logic within `encode_segment` was directly written in this closure
    let bytes = encode_segment(
        &mut buf_for_file,
        seek,
        workload,
        &stk_enc_rwl 
    );

    if let Err(_) = sndr_cl.send((i, bytes)) {
        better_exit(
            vec!["`rcvr` dropped before `sndr` clone(s) could finish"], 
            EXIT_CODE_DEV_ERR
        );
    }
});

Before attempting to use multi-threading, I played around with the optimization levels, since it seems that the resulting binary runs faster with opt-level = 2 instead of opt-level = 3.  So I thought that maybe Rust optimization magic may have something to do with it, but the runtime performance difference still persists despite using different levels of optimization.  Below are my release profile details:
[profile.release]
opt-level = 2
debug = false
split-debuginfo = 'packed'
lto = 'fat'
panic = 'abort'

I thought about potentially using rayon since it provides a high level way to implement parallelism with threadpooling, but I thought I'd benefit from using as much of the standard crates that Rust provides.
The only thing I changed from solution 1 (directly writing the logic within the thread closure) to solution 2 was extracting the majority of the logic to a separate function.
Has anyone experienced something like this?  Really stumped on how simply refactoring my code so that it's somewhat prettier to look at could increase performance so drastically.

Please add a [mre].

Consider adding #[inline] to encode_segment, and see how that effects things. Also, run a real benchmark that includes filesystem warming rounds, and see if you're spending more time in userspace or kernel space.

I ran some more tests and realized I must have done something wrong the first time... I embedded the encode_segment logic directly back into the thread closure, and it's running rather quickly.  Not sure what exactly went wrong the first time, but I think this question can be closed.
